# export spatial information from table that is joined to a shapefile in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, export, attribute-joins, table

I have a table with data values per district for different years. The table looks like this: 
district name / year / value. The same district is thus present in the data multiple times for different years. In QGIS I joined this table to a districts polygon Shapefile. THis creates a table with for every year a row with district name and value. Can I export this table in a way the spatial information of the district is stored in the table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/using-tabular-data-in-qgis.html

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial you reffering to is about joining a table to a shapefile, I just want it to do the other way around. I have a table like this: 1st row: Kampala | 2009 | value, 2nd row: Kampala | 2004 | value, etc. So multiple rows for the same district. I then joined the table to the Shapefile of districts. Now I want an exported table that shows per district row the spatial information (coordinates of corners) that looks like this: 1st row: Kampala | 2009 | value | polygon coordinates for Kampala, 2nd row: Kampala | 2004 | value | polygon coordinates for Kampala |

Comment: If you put both tables in Postgis or Spatialite, that would be very easy to obtain with a simple SQL statement. Another approach (generally more usefull in GIS) would be to join the year values in different columns without repeating the geometry. That is a column for each year.



 Another more GI

Comment: TimTensen: please edit the question with the extra details (just click edit below the question), and also add QGIS version, what you've already tried, and what you've already looked at. That helps to drive directly towards a useful answer instead of telling you things you already know.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your answers, I think I figured out how to create a csv WKT file of the districts and joined this to the csv table with the values. The only thing now is to convert this table that looks like this: district name | year | POLYGON ((29.815457304831565 -1.292311549298371,29.8162... etc. | to a Shapefile in QGis.. Save as doesnt seem to be the right solution. This is another question so I should make a new question?..

Comment: Edit the question.